# Android - Any available working template/library of sign-in using social networks?

Tags: android

Almost all Android apps require login activity. I wonder if there is any open source code for this. Is there any available activity implementation for handling sign-ins using major social networks like Facebook, G+ and Twitter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes SocialAuth is there.

It provides support for Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin, MySpace, FourSquare , Google , Google Plus, Runkeeper, Yammer , Yahoo, Instagram and Flickr

Check this [library](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)

[Step by step guide](http://blog.3pillarglobal.com/part-1-using-socialauth-integrate-facebook-api-android) to integrate SocialAuth into your app.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be ***[Parse](https://parse.com/products/social)***. According to the product page:

> Connect your users via traditional logins or third party social
>   networks with just a few lines of code.
>
> We take care of linking accounts across networks, resetting passwords,
>   and keeping everything safe and secure. The platform handles all the
>   tedious parts.